# How to construct a function from its graph?

Tags: haskell

I wonder if it is possible to make the inverse of the following function:

```
graphOf :: (Num a, Enum a) => (a -> b) -> [(a, b)]
graphOf f = [(e,v) | e <- [0..], v <- [f e]]
```

I mean I don't figure out how to write a Haskell function

```
fromGraph ::  (Enum a) => [(a, b)] -> (a -> b)
```

such that

```
fromGraph [(1,3),(2,4),(3,5)] :: (Num a) => a -> a
(fromGraph [(1,3),(2,4),(3,5)]) 1 == 3
(fromGraph [(1,3),(2,4),(3,5)]) 2 == 4
(fromGraph [(1,3),(2,4),(3,5)]) 3 == 5
```

Is it possible?
At least for finite input list?

Comment: Yes that is possible.

Comment: Unrelated: `[(e,v) | e <- [0..], v <- [f e]]` could be simplified to `[(e,v) | e <- [0..], let v = f e]` or even to `[(e,f e) | e <- [0..]]`. There's no need to construct a singleton list `[f e]` just to be able to extract from it (`v <- ...`).

Comment: You can capture the constraint that the graph has to be finite by using `Bounded` in place of `Enum` in the constraints.

Comment: See also my [universe](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe) package; it includes `Read` and `Show` instances for functions that include the ideas in this Q/A, and various other instances and operations that are likely to be useful in the same situations where you would want `graphOf` and `fromGraph`.

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way is to use [the `lookup` function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup):

```
Prelude> :m +Data.List
Prelude Data.List> lookup 1 [(1,3),(2,4),(3,5)]
Just 3
Prelude Data.List> lookup 2 [(1,3),(2,4),(3,5)]
Just 4
Prelude Data.List> lookup 3 [(1,3),(2,4),(3,5)]
Just 5
```

This is pretty inefficient though (for every query it just goes through the list linearly). You may want to back it with a faster lookup mechanism, using structures from the [`containers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) or [`unordered-containers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers) packages, for example

```
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HMS
import Data.Hashable (Hashable)

fastLookup :: Hashable k => [(k,b)] -> k -> Maybe b
fastLookup l = \k -> HMS.lookup k table
 where table = HMS.fromList l
```

Note that I wrote `fastLookup l = \k -> ...`. Do **not** simplify this to `fastLookup l k = ...`, because that would re-build the hash map for every query.

Answer (score 3):

You could write something like this

```hs
fromGraph :: [(Int, b)] -> Int -> b
fromGraph g i = snd (g !! i)
```

This would only work for `Int` indices, and would also assume that for every `i`, the element in the graph `g` at `g !! i` would have index `i` as well. If you want to do it a little more generically, you could write this:

```hs
fromGraph :: Eq a => [(a, b)] -> a -> b
fromGraph g i = snd $ head $ filter ((==i) . fst) g
```

Not that this would still throw an error if you try to use this function with an index that is not part of the graph.

Comment: In this case, I think a list comprehension is also quite a readable alternative to `filter`: `fromGraph g i = head [b | (a, b) <- g, a == i]`.